# arraylist<object > received in activity different from the one sent

Tags: android

I have database 1 contains all books data (name,id,description , and so on)
and i have another database contains id of books i added to favorite
i get the data in `asynctask`
first i get all books data from the first database and add them in `Arraylist<Book>` then i get the ids of favorite books ids from the second database and add them in `Arraylist<Integer>` and then compare and add a parameter in books to 1 if it's in favourite

```
    @Override
      protected ArrayList<Book> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> favlist = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> downlist = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
          if (mDBAdapter != null) {
          mDBAdapter.createDataBase();
          mDBAdapter.openDataBase();
          bookList = mDBAdapter.selectAllBooks();
        }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

      }
        if (mAnnotationDBAdapter!=null) {
          favlist = mAnnotationDBAdapter.selectAllFavourite();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <bookList.size() ; j++) {

          for (int i = 0; i <favlist.size() ; i++) {
            if (bookList.get(j).getId()==favlist.get(i))
              bookList.get(j).setInFavourite(1);
          }

    }
    return bookList;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    super.onPostExecute(books);
    if (books != null && books.size() > 0) {
      Intent mainActivityintent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
      mainActivityintent.putExtra(AppConstance.ALL_BOOKS_KEY,books);
      mContext.startActivity(mainActivityintent);
    }
  }
```

here books list is ok and has `infavourite` parameter = 1 if the book is in favorite table

but when i receive it in main activity
i got `infavourite` = 0

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    PublicMethod.mDBAdapter = new AnnotationDBAdapter(this);

      Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent != null) {

      if (intent.hasExtra(AppConstance.ALL_BOOKS_KEY)) {
        mBooks = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(AppConstance.ALL_BOOKS_KEY) ;
//here all book have infavourite = 0
      }
    }
```

Comment: is the Book object Serializable?

Comment: public class Book implements Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`